# Override NavigationBar's GetPositionForBar() using NavigationController - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

I'm using a NavigationController and I want its UINavigationBar's GetPositionForBar() method to always return `UIBarPosition.TopAttached`. As I'm using UINavigationController it's not possible to change the NavigationBar delegate, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

I tried a lot of things, one o them was:

```
public class CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController, IUINavigationBarDelegate
{
    [Export ("positionForBar:")]
    public UIBarPosition GetPositionForBar(IUIBarPositioning barPositioning)
    {
        return UIBarPosition.TopAttached;
    }
}
```

But it's not working. How can I do this? I'm using Xamarin/Monotouch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally created my own `UINavigationBar` manually and added it at the top of the View, this way I can change the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set WeakDelegate?  Something like

```
public class MyTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    public override void ViewDidLoad() {
        _searchController = new UISearchController();
        _searchController.SearchBar.WeakDelegate = this;
    }

    [Export ("positionForBar:")]
    public UIBarPosition GetPositionForBar(IUIBarPositioning barPositioning)
    {
        return UIBarPosition.TopAttached;
    }
}
```